# ClassCastException trying to run update preview

Tags: experience-manager, 2013, odata

I am getting a `java.lang.ClassCastException` after clicking on the Update Preview button.

The setup is using a standard Tridion 2013 Content Delivery stack (not the magic stuff some of you saw at #sdlinnovate), JSP-based site (tomcat) and JSP-hosted WebService for session preview. I get the following errors:

In odata's cd_core_log:
No errors logged.

In tomcat's access log:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Content Delivery Web service] in context with path [/preview-ws] threw exception
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataResponse cannot be cast to com.tridion.webservices.odata.input.handler.ODataBatchResponse
>       at com.tridion.webservices.odata.ODataWebservice.handleBatchRequest(ODataWebservice.java:147)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
>       at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)[...]

In Windows Event Viewer:

> Unable to update the changes using OData Service.
>   The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
>     Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService Errorcode: 1003 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE  StackTrace Information Details:
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveResult.BatchRequest(Boolean replaceOnUpdate)
>      at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions options)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService.ServiceImplementation.Preview(IEnumerable`1 publishedItemsInfo, TcmUri publishingTargetId)
>      at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PreviewService.ServiceImplementation.Preview(IEnumerable`1 publishedItemsInfo, TcmUri publishingTargetId)
>      at SyncInvokePreview(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

Any clues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it (thanks to Andrey G @ SDL)

The webservice ambient framework cartridge was commented out in cd_ambient_conf.xml.

```
<Cartridges>
    <Cartridge File="cd_webservice_preview_cartridge.xml"/>
</Cartridges>
```